# How to write a file using ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: java, file, file-io, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to write to a file and have now narrowed the problem down to the writeObject() method.

It is not writing the data to the file.

When i run oos.writeObject(siteData), nothing happens. The file remains empty

As you can see in the following code i have put in some System.out.println()s and they all return a full list

I have also been looking at it in the debugger step by step and it is not being overwritten later in the program.

I have also made sure that SiteData implements Serializable

What can cause this problem?

```
public void saveToStorageFile() throws IOException {

       System.out.println("saveToStorageStart() started!");

       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("SiteDataStorage"));
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

       //Prints the List
       for(int i = 0 ; i < this.size(); i++) {
           System.out.println("Save list:" + this.db.get(i).getText());
       }

       SiteData[] siteData = db.toArray(new SiteData[db.size()]);

       //Prints the sitedata array length
       System.out.println(siteData.length);

       oos.writeObject(siteData);
       oos.close();

       System.out.println("Saved!");
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Gustavo Closing a stream will flush it implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but the file is still empty

Comment: Are you sure that you're looking at the correct file? Try using an absolute path.

Comment: Are you crating more `new FileOutputStream(new File("SiteDataStorage"));`? Each time you do so old content of file is erased. Maybe you want to set it in append mode via `new FileOutputStream(new File("SiteDataStorage"), true);`?

Comment: Anyway to get proper help which will not involve guessing provide [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) so we could reproduce this problem on our machines  and debug it.

Comment: I gave i an absolute path, still empty

Comment: @Pshemo i added `true`, no difference.. and thank you, ill definitely look into that before making my next post

Comment: You must be looking at the wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

I've added this to make it a complete example.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class SiteData implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        new SiteData().saveToStorageFile();
    }
    private int size() { return 1; } // Did you not want db?
    private List<SiteData> db = List.of(this);
    private String getText() { return "Some text"; }
```

And appended the `}` to close the class.

Works for me!

Comment: I get a compile error: The method of(SiteData) is undefined for the type List

Comment: @TheJW If you're still using Java SE 8 for some reason, replace it with `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Strange, my file is till empty. maybe updating java will help?